# spinner have no elements while running the code

Tags: android

I add an spinner to toolbar and I fill it with elements but while running my app the spinner looks like empty
my code is `    @Override

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_tabs, menu);

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.spinner, menu);

    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.spinner);
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) item.getActionView();

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.listArray, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    return true;
}`
```

and the spinner menu is

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:title="category"
    app:actionViewClass="android.widget.Spinner"
    android:background="#ff00"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

and the array is

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="listArray">
        <item>first</item>
        <item>second</item>

    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Comment: Why do have two getMenuInflater() statements ?

Comment: @Lubna Al Anis you must add the spinner in your layout folder....For me  also i faced same problem..finally i done as i updated my answer...please check my answer..try it let me know

Comment: @GowthamanM hwo i will use the layout file ?

Comment: @GowthamanM how i will use the layout file ?

Comment: @ik024 because i have two menus in my toolbar

Answer (score 0):

Try in this way.

First create Spinner in your layout:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/dialog_spinner" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:spinnerMode="dialog"
    />
```

Here **SpinnerDemo.java**

```
 public class SpinnerDemo extends Activity {

   Spinner spinner;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);



        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        spinner.setVisiblity(View.Gone)
}
```

**Then Onclick of menu iteam**

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_tabs, menu);

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.spinner, menu);

    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.spinner);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.listArray, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.performClick();
    return true;
}`
```

Comment: it's give me an exception in  `spinner.setVisiblity(View.Gone)`

Comment: @LubnaAlAnis post your exeception